# Is there a way to show the TFS changeset number after a check-in?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, changeset, checkin, tfs-power-tools

Is there a way, with power tools or other extensions, to make it so that the changeset number is be displayed on an alert?

Currently it displays on the status bar, but disappears after a while, or at least make this more prominent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output from TFS commands shows up in Visual Studio's Output window, but you need to change the "Show output from" dropdown to "Source Control - Team Foundation". Check-ins will produce output like:

```
Changeset 1234567 successfully checked in.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup alerts in TFS which sends you an email with the checkin information, including the changeset number. There is an limited alert editor shipped with visual studio (see in the menu Team -> Project Alerts). You can choose the option "Anything checked in"

There are also the [power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) which give an editor with more options. You can then filter also on user name. But be aware that everybody should set up their own alert.

Comment: thanks, will I get other team members check ins also? or just mine?

Comment: ANything that is checked in. So also from your team members. If you want to restrict that, use the email editor from the power tools.

Comment: cool thanks for the help, managed to set the conditions through the "Alerts Explorer" option in the Team menu option.